# Prediction Intervals for Poisson Regression Totals by Year

Tags: r, prediction, survey, poisson

I am conducting a study using a survey design to predict the total number of procedures per year in a dataset from 2017 to 2030. I am currently using Poisson regression to create these predictive estimates.

```
  svydesign(
    data = four,
    strata = ~NIS_STRATUMnew,
    ids = ~NISIDnew,
    weights = ~DISCWTnew,
    nest = T
  )
```

I am able to successfully use the following to generate estimates and accurate confidence intervals for the years that we have data (prior to 2017):

`kneetotal1<- svyby(~kneePJI, ~YEAR, design = mydesign, FUN = svytotal, vartype = "ci")`

However, when I try to calculate prediction intervals for the estimates I run into issues (my prediction intervals are way too narrow), either if I try to directly use my data to make predictions (1) or if I use the svyby (2) results to make predictions:

(1)

```
AdjPoissonKnee <- svyglm(kneePJI ~ YEAR, family = poisson(), design = mydesign)
years <- data.frame(YEAR = 2018:2030)
predictHip <- predict(AdjPoissonHip, newdata = data.frame(YEAR = 2018:2030), type = "response", se.fit =TRUE, interval = "predict")
```

(This just seems to produce likelihood per person of a procedure. I am not sure how to yield a yearly cumulative sum for this, along with confidence intervals)

(2)

```
futureyears <- data.table(YEAR = 2018:2030)
AdjPoissonKnee <- glm(kneePJI ~ YEAR, family = poisson(), data=kneetotal1)
kneepredict <- predict(object = AdjPoissonKnee, newdata=futureyears, type = "response")
```

The dataset is extremely large, so that may be contributing to the issue of very narrow prediction intervals. Lmk if there is a way I can help by adding a snippet of some data.

Example output (2) combined with svyby of 2002-2017:
[image]

```
kneetotal1<- svyby(~kneePJI, ~YEAR, design = mydesign, FUN = svytotal, vartype = "ci")

> kneetotal1 
YEAR    kneePJI 
2002    8205.194 
2003    9648.019 
2004    10362.076 
2005    11771.961 
2006    12099.399 
2007    12993.681 
2008    15438.871 
2009    14303.562 
2010    16051.562 
2011    17158.166 
2012    17055.006 
2013    18064.991 
2014    19080.006 
2015    19429.988 
2016    18070.002 
2017    18399.995

AdjPoissonKnee <- glm(kneePJI ~ YEAR, family = poisson(), data=kneetotal1)
kneese <- predict(object = AdjPoissonKnee, newdata=futureyears, type = "response", interval = "prediction", se.fit =TRUE)

> kneese
$fit
       1        2        3        4        5        6        7        8        9       10       11       12       13 
22107.84 23232.34 24414.04 25655.84 26960.81 28332.15 29773.25 31287.64 32879.07 34551.44 36308.87 38155.70 40096.46 

$se.fit
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11        12        13 
 87.14235 100.68424 115.63713 132.05885 150.02228 169.61303 190.92798 214.07449 239.16993 266.34157 295.72666 327.47263 361.73741 

> stderrKnee <- kneese$se.fit
> predfitKnee <- kneese$fit
> reserrsqKnee <- predfitKnee^2*summary(AdjPoissonKnee)$dispersion^2
> prederrsqKnee <- stderrKnee^2 + reserrsqKnee
> lower_pi <- predfitKnee - 1.96 * sqrt(prederrsqKnee)
> upper_pi <- predfitKnee + 1.96 * sqrt(prederrsqKnee)
> lower_pi
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11        12        13 
-21223.86 -22303.48 -23438.01 -24630.27 -25883.19 -27199.86 -28583.52 -30037.57 -31565.61 -33171.39 -34858.88 -36632.22 -38495.80
> upper_pi
        1         2         3         4         5         6         7         8         9        10        11        12        13 
 65439.55  68768.16  72266.09  75941.96  79804.81  83864.16  88130.01  92612.86  97323.74 102274.27 107476.62 112943.62 118688.72
```

Answer (score 1):

One problem  is that `predict.svyglm` doesn't **have** an `interval="predict"` option (you don't get an error,  because methods in R are required to accept and ignore arguments they don't understand, so that inheritance works)

However, it won't make that much difference.  The standard deviation of a Poisson variable with a mean of 20000 is $\sqrt{20000}$, or about 141, and adding $1.96\times 141$ to your interval half-width won't make a huge difference.

It's quite likely that your data are overdispersed with respect to a Poisson distribution: if you do `summary(AdjPoissonKnee)` (for the `svyglm`), part of the output is  an estimated dispersion parameter, which I'm guessing will be larger than 1, meaning that the predictive distribution shouldn't be Poisson.

This is part of **why** `predict.svyglm` doesn't currently do prediction intervals.  Consider a Poisson distribution. It's discrete. What even should the prediction interval be?

It would be possible to create a prediction interval that estimated the dispersion parameter and then approximated the predictive distribution by a Normal distribution with the correct variance. Peter Ellis discusses this approach [here](http://freerangestats.info/blog/2020/04/18/pred-interval-from-log-linear) for ordinary glms, and his code could be  adapted: you would do (untested, because I don't have your data)

```
AdjPoissonKnee <- svyglm(kneePJI ~ YEAR, 
       family = poisson(), design = mydesign)
years <- data.frame(YEAR = 2018:2030)
predictHip <- predict(AdjPoissonKnee, 
      newdata = data.frame(YEAR = 2018:2030), 
       type = "response", se.fit =TRUE) 

stderr<-SE(predictHip)
predfit<-coef(predictHip)

reserrsq<- predfit^2*summary(AdjPoissonKnee)$dispersion^2

prederrsq <- stderr^2 + reserrsq

lower_pi <- predfit - 1.96 * sqrt(prederrsq)
upper_pi <- predfit + 1.96 * sqrt(prederrsq)
```

Comment: Thanks! I will try this

Comment: I now get negative values for the lower pi, but the prediction intervals are indeed larger as you recommended. Is there some adjustment I should make? Thanks!